# How to know the size of this array

Tags: java

I have a question regarding the arrays..
 Suppose that I have an object (A) which contains an array of unknown size, and I don't have any access to the array size or the array itself , however I can apply the following methods on the object A:

- empty
- full
- add(after the last element)
- remove(the last element; this returns the element removed)

How can I know the size of the array ??

Comment: [Oracle's Tutorial on Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. You can probably test how many times you can call the remove method.

Comment: you can write a method in its class so that the method have access to array then it will return size of array ( array.length)

Comment: What code have you attempted? What process have you thought would work? What are your ideas so far?

Comment: Are you allowed to destroy the array when making the measurement?

Comment: No, I can't add any thing to the class A .

Comment: No I am required to keep the order of the array elements

Comment: Why can't I solve it ?

Comment: put elements to stack in a loop and count the iterations. Then push everything back.

Comment: Does `remove` return a reference to the element removed?

Comment: it returns the element itself

Comment: That is very important. Answer below.

Answer (score 2):

first call add till the Array is full, then remove and count how many times you removed till the Array is empty, you have the size, like this:

```
    SomeArray a = ...
    SomeThingThatArrayCanStore something = ...;

    while (!a.full()) {
       a.add(something);
    }

    int size = 0;

    while (!a.empty()) {
       a.remove()
       size++;
    }

    // here you have the size
```

Comment: Maybe you should clone the input array first, in order to refrain from destroying it during the process.

Comment: Sounds great, but I will loose the elements of the array !

Comment: This is the only solution. If remove() returns the element that is removed, then store it in some other array, and add them all after you know the size (in this moment the array is empty)

Comment: but what will be the size of the temprory array ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `full`: that's a red herring.

Here's a solution that achieves this without explicitly creating a temporary container. Essentially I'm using the stack frames to build a container of removed elements.

If `A` is the type of the array, and `a` the instance, and the `remove()` function returns the object removed, then

```
int size(int n, A a){    
    if (a.empty()){
        return n; // all done, n holds the number of elements removed
    }
    Object o = a.remove(); // pop the element
    int ret = size(n + 1, a); // call self with the array truncated
    a.add(o); // push the element back
    return ret;
}
```

is one way, if you call it initially with `n` set to zero. It's ruinously expensive when it comes to the creation of stack frames, but has a strange elegance to it.

Comment: Here you only know how many elements is in the array, not the size of the array itself (how many elements it can store).

Answer (score 0):

Try something fun with reflection : Reflection allow you to acces private field and unknown field. It is like dark magic : powerfull but dangerous !

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayFinder  {

    public void printAllArraysLength(A a) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        for (Field field : A.class.getDeclaredFields()) {       // get all private fields
            field.setAccessible(true);      // private are now public !
            Object array = field.get(a);    // get the field content.
            try{
                System.out.println(field.getName() + " length : " +  getArrayLenth(array));
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(field.getName() + " is not an array");
            }
        }
    }

    private int getArrayLenth(Object array) {
        Class arrayClass = array.getClass().getComponentType();
        if(arrayClass == null){
            // no component type, maybe a list.
            return  ((List) array).size();
        }
        else {
            if (arrayClass.isPrimitive()) {
                return   Array.getLength(array);
            }else{
                return   ((Object[]) array).length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, that's probably not what your teacher expect you to do with add / remove / empty and full.